# Jquery Redirect to image src or data-attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On a image inside link instead of use link href i would like to use img src to redirect to image path.

with this is possible to get the img src but how to use src to redirect? thank's

```
 $(".drop a").click( function() {
     alert($(this).children('img').attr('src'));
 });

<div class="drop">
<a href""><img src=".." /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Does alert gives you proper URL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I redirect to another page in JavaScript/jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-page-in-javascript-jquery)

Comment: @Rajesh yes! give

Comment: Then please refer duplicate link to see different approaches to redirect and if it satisfies your requirement, accept this as duplicate so that no one answers it

Comment: that is a redirect this is redirect based on img src. don't get consused @Rajesh

Comment: You are  able to get url in a variable, so  the real  problem was *How to redirect using this value*. So yes its a duplicate. Fetching url from img is  a specific usecase but underlying problem and solution are same

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just use `window.location`

**Code:-**

```
$(".drop a").click( function() {

     window.location = $(this).children('img').attr('src');
     return false;
});
```

Comment: Though your answer is correct, you should choose to close it as duplicate as this is a very obvious duplicate